# How to prove that Limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(n\pi)$ doesn´t exist, or exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation, infinity

I believe that when n tends to infinity, the expression $\cos(n\pi)$ doesn´t converge, because the oscilation values. But, how can we formally prove that?
Thank you!!

Comment: Have you taken any analysis courses? If not, I suggest checking out the epsilon definition of a sequence limit first, as you need it to prove the limit doesn't exist. If so, lots of great answers below.

Comment: The easiest proof in my opinion is the subsequence one. If the sequence converged, then any subsequence of that sequence would also converge (and to the same thing). However, you can find two subsequence's that converge to different things, and so the original sequence can't converge. Just as written by @Vitor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is even $cos(n\pi) = 1$, and if $n$ is odd $cos(n\pi) = -1$. So, there is a subsequence ($cos(2n\pi)$) that converges to $1$ and another subsequence ($cos((2n+1)\pi)$) that converges to $-1$. So, the sequence does not converge.

Comment: Easiest solution in my opinion, nice. ${+1}$

Comment: Perfect, now I understand. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just do the definition.

If $\lim_{n\to \infty} \cos (n\pi) = a$ then any $\epsilon > 0$ the there is an $N$ so that if $n > N$ then $|\cos(n\pi)-a| < \epsilon$.

Well if $n$ is even than $\cos (n\pi) = 1$ and if $n$ is odd then $\cos (n\pi)=-1$.

So *both*  $|1- a| < \epsilon$ and $|-1 -a | < \epsilon$ which can be shown to be impossible for $\epsilon \le 1$ by the triangle inequality.

$2= |-1-1|=|(-1-a) +(a-1)|\le |-1 + a|+|a-1|=|-1+a|+|1-a|< \epsilon + \epsilon = 2\epsilon < 2$.

A contradiction.  so $\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos(n\pi) \ne a$ for and $a\in \mathbb R$.

I'll leave it to you to show $\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos(n\pi) \ne \pm \infty$.

($\lim_{n\to \infty}\cos(n\pi) =\infty$ would imply for any $M\in \mathbb R$ there is an $N$ so that $n > N$ would mean $\cos(n\pi) >M$  but $\cos (n\pi) \le 1$.)

Answer (score 0):

If the limit exists, then the sequence $(x_n)$ given by $x_n:=\cos(\pi n), n\in\Bbb N$ converges as well.  The sequence isn't Cauchy though, because of the oscillation.  Successive terms differ by at least $2$.  More precisely, given $\epsilon\lt2$, there is no $N$ such that $n,m\ge N\implies|x_n-x_m|\lt\epsilon$.